# Pygame Class Player not moving when I press key

Tags: python, pygame

I created a class of the player and I instantiated it and it doesn't work when I try to move it.
I don't understand what is wrong.
I thought the problem was in the order of the functions but isn't it.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from variabile import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))

def ecranAlb():
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def display(self):
        rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,100,100)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,0),rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.x = self.x + 2




running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    a = Player(100,100)
    
    ecranAlb()
    a.move()
    a.display()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the instance object of the `Player` class before the application loop. When you do it in the loop, then the a new object at the initial position is generated in each frame:

```py
a = Player(100,100)       # <--- INSERET

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    # a = Player(100,100)   <--- DELETE
    
    ecranAlb()
    a.move()
    a.display()
    pygame.display.flip()
```